# How to apply mutliple rotate values for one image in imgaug? (Not randomly)

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, data-augmentation

```
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa
from imgaug import parameters as iap

import cv2

aug=iaa.Affine(rotate=iap.DeterministicList([90,180,270]))


imglist = []

img = cv2.imread('i/1.jpg')

imglist.append(img)

images_aug = aug.augment_images(imglist)

cv2.imwrite('i/new.jpg', images_aug[0])
```

I have this code and want to apply my 3 rotation values(90,180,270) to an image. so my output should be 3 images(rotated with 90,180,270 angles versions of an image) but when I use this code, it assigns a random rotate value and gives me one rotated image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want:

```py
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa
from imgaug import parameters as iap
import cv2

rotations = [90,180,270]
aug = iaa.Affine(rotate=iap.DeterministicList(rotations))
img = cv2.imread('i/1.jpg')
imglist = [img for i in range(len(rotations))]
images_aug = aug.augment_images(imglist)
for i in range(len(rotations)):
    cv2.imwrite('i/new_{}.jpg'.format(rotations[i]), images_aug[i])
```

The changes are:

- We have an array of rotations, which is used throughout the code. This just helps to shorten the subsequent code.
- We add enough `img`s to `imglist` to cover every rotation.
- We output each image from `images_aug`.

End result:

[image: woof woof woof woof]